# Create a polygon from line intersections

Tags: r

I would like to create a polygon from the area that is delineated by the four lines (a,b,c,d) from the example below. Would be great if you could help me out!

```
a <- data.frame (x  = c(1, 5, 9),
                  y = c(1, 0, 1))
b <- data.frame (x  = c(2, 2),
                 y = c(0, 5))
c <- data.frame (x  = c(1, 9),
                 y = c(4, 4))
d <- data.frame (x  = c(8, 8),
                 y = c(0, 5))

a <- a %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y")) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(do_union=FALSE) %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING") 
b <- b %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y")) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(do_union=FALSE) %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING") 
c <- c %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y")) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(do_union=FALSE) %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING") 
d <- d %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y")) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(do_union=FALSE) %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING")

ggplot() + geom_sf(data=a) + geom_sf(data=b) + geom_sf(data=c) + geom_sf(data=d)
```

Comment: Polygons are 'closed' by repeating the beginning, i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4 (linestrings), becomes 1,2,3,4,1 (polygon), a list of linestrings that you can st_cast. You'll likely want to rename `c` as it is also a function ?c name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is precisely what `st_polygonize` does

```r
list(a, b, c, d) |>
  purrr::reduce(sf::st_union) |> 
  st_polygonize() |>
  ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(fill = "lightblue") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 20)
```

[image]